# PHPickerViewController swipe to dismiss stops working after selecting photo

Tags: ios, swift, phpickerviewcontroller, interactive-dismissal

I present a `PHPickerViewController` as a pagesheet. It is possible to close/dismiss the picker interactively by just swiping down (or tapping outside on iPad).

However once you tap a photo this no longer works. The pagesheets does move a bit if you try but it just snaps back.

I tried setting the presentationController delegate but shouldDismiss() never gets called. Deselecting the photo by tapping again has no effect either. `isModalInPresentation` gets ignored too, also when you use it in the callback after you select a photo.

To try it out yourself just use this line:

```swift
present(PHPickerViewController(configuration: PHPickerConfiguration()), animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?